# Why my database only updates when I create another table?

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, mariadb, heidisql

I am using Jupyter notebook to run some SQL queries. The queries are working because I can print them on my screen using `pd.read_sql`
Here is the code to insert the data in the SQL table:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE table_1 (col_1 INT, col_2 INT, col_3 DOUBLE, col_4 DOUBLE, col_5 DOUBLE, col_6 BIGINT)")
query = 'INSERT INTO table_1 (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'                                                        
my_data = []

for row in data_df:
    my_data.append(tuple(row))
cur.executemany(query, my_data)
```

To read the table in jupyter:

```
pd.read_sql( '''SELECT * FROM table_1''',conn)
```

[Inserting data into table in Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWDGd.png).
I try to see this inserted data in HeidiSQL but I don't know why the inserted rows are not updated. On the Database tab it says there are  the corresponding rows but once I click the table to see the data it says 0 rows. [Rows are not updating in HeidiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSiOR.png)
Then when I create another table the previous one gets updated and I can actually see the rows in HeidiSQL [Updated table only when a new table is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIe1D.png).

Answer (score 0):

First, can you try to copy your code and result (especially your code) into your question (not link) so we can copy paste to try/debug/correct it

based on your image, I think you need to commit it

```
cur.executemany(query, my_data)
cur.commit()
```

Comment: I have added the code. When I try it with cur.commit() the following error appears:  " 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit' ". Could it be conn.commit () to commit the connection?

Comment: Should be cursor.execute("COMMIT") or connection.commit().